# Magento upgrade error 2.4.5 in php 8.1 json_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($json) of type string is deprecated

Tags: magento2.4.5, json, deprecated

I am facing after an issue after upgrading version magneto 2.4.2 to 2.4.5 When I run this command I got error

json_decode(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($json) of type string is deprecated

app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php(495): json_decode(NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
**Additional context**

Try to use null coleascing operator:

public function getParametersAttribute()
{
   -. return $cookieValue=json_decode($cookieValue);
}

public function getParametersAttribute()
{
   +. return $cookieValue= json_decode($cookieValue ?? '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code
**1. Add string (string)**

```
public function getParametersAttribute()
{
   return $cookieValue=json_decode((string)$cookieValue);
}
```

**2. Add condition**

```
public function getParametersAttribute(){
if (isset($cookieValue)) {
   return $cookieValue=json_decode($cookieValue);
 }else{
    return [];
  }
}
```

**3. Try this one**

```
public function getParametersAttribute(){
   return $cookieValue= json_decode($cookieValue ?? '');
}
```